# Multiple returning

Tags: php, function

Could anyone help me. 
I need to return multiple img's, but with this code, only one of two is returning.
What is the solution.
Thank you in advance.

```
$test = "/claim/img/box.png, /claim/img/box.png";


function test($test) 
{
            $photo = explode(',', $test);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($photo); $i++)
                {

                    $returnas = "<img src=".$photo[$i].">";
                    return $returnas;
                }

}
```

Comment: You want to know about arrays.

Comment: The return statement stops the function. No code inside the function will be executed after you return. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 6):

This might be a good opportunity to learn about [`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map).

```
function test($test) {
    return implode("",array_map(function($img) {
        return "<img src='".trim($img)."' />";
    },explode(",",$test)));
}
```

Many functions make writing code a lot simpler, and it's also faster because it uses lower-level code.

---

While we're on the subject of learning things, PHP 5.5 gives us [generators](http://php.net/generators). You could potentially use one here. For example:

```
function test($test) {
    $pieces = explode(",",$test);
    foreach($pieces as $img) {
        yield "<img src='".trim($img)."' />";
    }
}
```

That `yield` is where the magic happens. This makes your function behave like a generator. You can then do this:

```
$images = test($test);
foreach($images as $image) echo $image;
```

Personally, I think this generator solution is a lot cleaner than the `array_map` one I gave earlier, which in turn is tidier than manually iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code that way

```
function test($test) 
{
    $returnas = '';
    $photo = explode(',', $test);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($photo); $i++)
    {
        $returnas .= "<img src=".$photo[$i].">";
    }
    return $returnas;
}
```

Your code didn't work since you were returning inside the loop immediatly. Every programming language support "only a return for call". In my solution you're appendig a string that has an img tag each time you enter the loop and return it after every photo is "passed" into the loop

You could even use the [`foreach()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct, of course

### Bonus answer

If you don't know the difference between ...

`for ($i = 0; $i < count($photo); $i++)`

and

`for ($i = 0, $count = count($photo); $i < $<; $i++)`

Well, in first case you'll evaluate `count($photo)` every single time the for is called whereas the second time, it is evaluated only once.

This could be used for optimization porpuses (even if php, internally, stores the length of an array so it is accesible in `O(1)`)

Comment: @user3553224: Niet the Dark Absol answer is better ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function breaks after the first `return` statement. You need to save what you want to return in some structure, an array eg, and return this.

```
function test($test) 
{
    $result = array();
    $photo = explode(',', $test);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($photo); $i++)
    {
        $returnas = "<img src=".$photo[$i].">";
        $result[] = $returnas;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yep, missed the `[]`, sorry